# Laravel Spatie Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

In the index of my user controller I have the following:

```
return QueryBuilder::for(User::class)
    ->with('phoneNumbers')
    ->allowedIncludes('trashed')
    ->get();
```

I was hoping to pass an include param like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/users?include=trashed
```

To append the `withTrashed()` global scope to the query.

Is this possible? I am most likely missing something obvious, I have tried a few variations in my testing usually ending up with an error like:

```
"message": "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on boolean",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
    "file": "/Users/timwickstrom/Sites/Wavefire/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
    "line": 522,
```

For reference:
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder[enter link description here](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder)

Comment: check if `phoneNumbers` exists or returns a Relation for the class `User`

Comment: Can't you just use `withTrashed()`? I think it's the problem, when you use it in `allowedIncludes`, it's treated as a relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking out that library, here's what I've got.

```
return QueryBuilder::for(User::class)
    ->with('phoneNumbers') // <-- I think you can use `allowedIncludes` here.
    ->allowedFilters([ // <-- I believe that `withTrashed` is a scope query,
                       // so you can use this. You cannot use `allowedIncludes`
                       // because it works with relations.
        Filter::scope('withTrashed')
    ])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. After reading this and rereading the docs I still cannot get it to include the global withTrashed. i tried passing it ?filter['trashed'], ?filter['withTrashed'], ?filter['with_trashed']. Never added it. But it did give me inspiration on how to solve it. So thanks you.

Comment: Actually this does work! Thank you. There was one missing peice in my testing the value of the filter. withTrashed does not except params but you still need to pass true like so: http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/users?filter[withTrashed]=true

Comment: it's good that it worked! Sorry, I don't have any idea about the url thingy, is that included in the library?

Comment: No, that's the route I defined that I was testing with. This part ?filter[withTrashed]=true is how you interface with the QueryBuilder. I was simply passing ?filter[withTrashed] which wasn't triggering the query builder. When I added =true or =1 it would include the scope.

Answer (score 0):

A late note that this is now natively supported in the package.

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v5/features/filtering

```
QueryBuilder::for(Booking::class)
    ->allowedFilters([
        AllowedFilter::trashed(),
    ]);

// GET /bookings?filter[trashed]=only will only return soft deleted models
```